# Sharing Terraform tfvars among organization

Tags: security, terraform

I am new to cloud development and I am trying to learn how variables are shared among organizations.
Suppose I create a terraform infrastructure and a state file is stored on Remote s3 bucket. Now I give all the variables via terraform.tfvars file and store them on my machine and do not commit that file to the repository.
Now If another developer wants to change the infrastructure, he has to know the values of tfvars (terraform.tfvars or backend.tfvars) files. How will I share with him securely?

For example:

In my terraform.tfvars I have

```
region="us-east-1"
vpc_cidr="192.168.0.0/16"
vpc_name="my-vpc"
Rds_password="password" 
Rds_username="username"
```

Now when some have to make a change to my infrastructure they need all the above values, So how will I share my terraform.tfvars file? The solution should scale to many developers

Comment: The examples you've shared here seem like values that I would typically include in directly in my version control repository as part of the configuration, rather than as external variables. Can you edit your question to include the reason why you want to keep these values separate? There are some different possible answers to this question and so which would be best for you will depend on your reasons and goals.

Comment: I updated the vars to have rds username and password. Also if any sensitive values that should be committed to version control. How would you approach?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to address this problem:

- using Terraform Cloud, you can store the secret variables remotely so that you do not have to commit your secrets to git
- using an external secrets provider, like Hashicorp Vault or one of the cloud based ones. You store your secrets there and only reference them in your tf code
- encrypt the secrets on a file in the repo via sops, and read in Terraform with https://registry.terraform.io/providers/carlpett/sops/